# Mapping Shiro exceptions at the service layer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, shiro

I'm using Spring 3.2.3 and Shiro 1.2.0 to secure access to a service. This works, but results in throwing a Shiro-specific exception. I'd like to throw an application-specific exception instead. Is this possible, either with Shiro or mapping at the Spring level? I know I can map controller exceptions to views with Spring, but I'm not sure how to handle it at the service layer. My setup:

Service interface:

```
public interface CaseService {
  Case getCase(Integer id);
}
```

Service implementation:

```
@Service
public class CaseServiceImpl implements CaseService {
  @RequiresAuthentication
  public Case getCase(Integer id) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

When testing the above without an authenticated Subject, I do receive an exception as expected, but it is a org.apache.shiro.* one. I tried using Spring's @ExceptionHandler to handle the Shiro exception. It had no effect, but I think it needs to work at the controller layer.

Comment: out of curiosity, why didn't you choose Spring Security instead of  Apache Shiro?

Comment: I started to use Spring Security on a previous project, but had trouble getting it to work (I can no longer remember the issue). I tried Shiro and got it to work pretty easily, so now I'm more familiar with it. When I have time I'll probably give SS another look, but so far I've been able to do what I've wanted with Shiro, except for the custom exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't a reason you absolutely need use the @RequiresAuthentication annotation you can call the following custom utility class to return the exception you require.

```
public class UserAuthenticationUtil {
  /**
   * Check that the current user bound to {@link ThreadLocal} is authenticated.
   * @throws ApplicationSpecificException If the current user is not authenticated.
   */
  public static void checkUserAuthenticated () throws ApplicationSpecificException {
    if (!SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated()) {
      throw new ApplicationSpecificException("User is not authenticated!");
    }
  }
}
```

[Here is the code/class](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/shiro/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/authz/aop/AuthenticatedAnnotationHandler.java) that handles the @RequiresAuthentication annotation if you'd like to verify it is the same logic.  [Here is the API documenation](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.1/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authz/annotation/RequiresAuthentication.html) as well.

Comment: Thanks, Justin. That's a good idea. Using the utility class takes the same number of lines in the application code, and gives me control over exceptions.